# How to get Max of ID without use of MAX()

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, max

I want to get the maximum id from table with ought use of any function like max or else.I need simple pure query.Any one help me to solve this problem .
We simply write

```
select max(id) from table
```

but i don't want to use **max()**

Comment: So, why exactly have you created this artificial "problem"?

Comment: no this question ask me in my job interview so i need ans of this ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT id
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**ORDER BY** with **LIMIT**  will do the job for u just fine

```
 SELECT id FROM table 
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But as you asked the question from interview's point of view , they may even ask you to do the same without using **LIMIT**  ,  **TOP**  or  ***max()*** . 
In thay case you should go with *subquery* approach . Here' s how u should do it :

```
  SELECT id FROM table 
  WHERE  id >=  ALL
 (SELECT id FROM table)
```

In this query an id is matched with all the id's in the table and it will be printed only if the value is greater than or equal to all the id's in the table. Only the max will satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ORDER BY** clause with **LIMIT** to fetch latest ID of table

Try this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

I added 0 to solve the problem,

```sql
select max(id + 0) from table
```